# how to create custom listadapter class in android studio

Tags: android

i switched eclipse to android studio i m little bit confuse on working android studio and i was working on listview app but custom adapter class not inherit to  parent class .

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

 custom cos=new custom(this);

 lv.setAdapter(cos);
```

}

---

..but  custom name java class not inherit to parent class in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of 
public class YourClassName extends BaseAdapter{
.... its method

}